# HDMI Splitter 2 different size tv's

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, karaoke

I have an HP Laptop that I use for my karaoke business. I use an HDMI splitter and usually have no problems. A new venue that I started has an 80inch TV on the stage and the owner wants me to hook into that. When I split between the 80inch and my 24inch (for the singer), the video signal will drop a few times each night. do I need a certain splitter for the drastic difference is size or something? I never have problems with my other venues. I split 3 46inch with no problems.I've decided it has to be the 80inch TV. Thanks for any input.

Comment: 80inch doesn't tell you anything about the actual technical side. What resolution is it running at? What HDMI version does either display use? You probably should check the manual of the splitter for any important technical details on limitations.

Comment: Size of display doesn't matter. Did cable lengths change?

Answer (score 2):

The size of the output devices are irrelevant.  What matters is the signal.  Since it appears both displays work, at least somewhat, we know the signal is being accepted by both displays.  I *assume* you are using a passive Y splitter.  This is probably the source of the problem.  When splitting signals with a passive device, you are reducing the quality of the signal.  Essentially the power of the signal is split in half to be sent to both outputs.  That coupled with long HDMI cables can cause signal dropouts.  HDMI has a 50 foot maximum length, but Im sure that will drop drastically with a degraded signal from a passive Y splitter.  You need an *active* HDMI splitter that will boost the signal being split to both sources.  Active splitters typically are plugged into a wall outlet and use that power to send the proper signal to its outputs.

Comment: I am using a fit tek 1 x 2 HDMI Splitter. It plugs in, not a Y splitter. I use 2 - 25 ft HDMI cables. I am really baffled by this. Thanks for your input. Maybe I need a higher quality splitter?

Comment: @TinaCreechleyReynolds I think its worth a shot.